# FB Business verification error - Something went wrong. We're working on getting this fixed as soon as we can. You may be able to try again

Tags: facebook, whatsapp, facebook-batch-request, facebook-business-sdk, facebook-business-manager

I am working on a new business and created my page on FB. I tried to verify my business as per instructions at [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M6sH9.jpg) link on fb.

The instruction article has a hyperlinked for security centre whcih opens a page with pre-populated values (which are correct values). When I clicked the "NEXT" button to goto next section, I got following error.

"*Something went wrong. We're working on getting this fixed as soon as we can. You may be able to try again*."

I tested this on 3 different browsers (safari, firefox and chrome) and this behaior is showing up. I further browser based extensions, ad blockers, content blockers etc for the purpose of testing this issue and this issue is coming up on all scenarios.

I raised this issue with fb help & support link on my fb page but I have not heard from them yet. I did not get any acknowledgement either. (*hey fb, are you listening?*)

I have all legal documents in place to upload. But neither the system allow me to do so nor anyone seems to have taken responsibility to fix this.

I am wondering that this flow must have been used by many who verified their business. Anyone to look at the situation and help me to get my business verified.?

Note : I have completed followng steps.

1. Buiness information primary page created successfully
2. Connected a WhatsApp account
3. Brand Safty (Domain cerificaion) completed successfully

**Just the "Business Verifiaion Status" is unverified and I want to have it verified.**

I appreciate possiible help to solve this problem.

See the error screen below.[FB business showing error on clicking NEXT bytton](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M6sH9.jpg)

Comment: Same issue here... Did you get a solution?